# What race should I genocide?

Tags: nethack

I just got a scroll of genocide monster. My initial reaction is to kill off vampires, because I hate losing levels to them. However, I'm not sure that this is the best monster to genocide. There are still mindflayers and wights, and loads of other nasties.

What are some of the top creatures that I should consider genociding?

Comment: Blessed-Genocide elves. (Don't actually do this)

Comment: If you're frequently losing levels to vampires, your problem is most likely that you're neglecting to wear an MC3 cloak (or mithril).

Comment: Oh, good point Wooble.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some of the [most popular genocides](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Genocide#Common_genocides) are:

- Liches (due to powerful magic like destroy armor and touch of death)
- Mind Flayers (due to their brain-eating attacks)
- Sea Monsters (due to their ability to drown - a 1-turn kill)
- Rust Monsters & Disenchanters (due to them weakening weapons and armor)

When you have a scroll of genocide, you should consider waiting to bless it before you use it.  A blessed scroll wipes out an entire *class* of monster, while an uncursed one only wipes out a single species.

You may also consider *cursing* your scroll of genocide.  This will create 4-6 monsters of the chosen species (commonly referred to as [reverse-genociding](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Genocide#Reverse_genocide)).  This can be useful.  For example, some people prefer to reverse genocide silver or grey dragons to get scales for DSM, rather than having to use a wish.  Others pick wraiths to eat for levels, or giants to eat for strength.

Comment: Note that if you're a dwarf, you should absolutely *not* bless your scrolls before trying to get rid of mind flayers and master mind flayers; do them with an uncursed scroll individually, since genociding `h` will kill you too.

Comment: Another popular race to reverse-genocide are nurses. Summoning a couple of nurses in sokoban or another no-teleport level is an easy way to gain some HP.

Comment: @Wooble - That an also be a good use for genocides from sitting on a throne.